# Categories error in Varien Data Tree DB class

Tags: category, error, products, fatal-error

I keep running into this error in my Magento backend.

I changed some categories and soon after that I ran into this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   /home/test1039/domains/sambalshop.portalserver.nl/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Tree/Dbp.php
>   on line 331

I only see the error on the categories page. The rest of my Magento environment works fine.

Comment: please enable magento log and check the log file ar var/log folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into admin which will still be working and under `System`, select `Manage Shops` and click on your shop name.

Your root category will be empty, simply select the correct root category.

Comment: Nice thinking, the root category is empty indeed. Although when I click the dropdown box, there aren't any categories there to select.

Comment: Sounds like you accidently deleted your categories or the category database is broken. Do you see any categories in the frontend?

Comment: I think the category database might be the problem. I don't see any categories on the frontend and the category tables are empty.